# Invoke static method in static class C# ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've placed a static class TestClass in the App_Code folder. The class contains a static method TestMethod. From Default.aspx.cs via Button_Click method, I'm trying to invoke TestMethod. - test = TestClass.TestMethod(). 
This gives error: 'TestClass' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

It feels like the static class and the _Default class should be placed into a common namespace, but this would "exclude" the Default.aspx controls references.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: here is a good link to look at that will explain Access Modifiers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare `TestClass` as public:

```
public static class TestClass
{
    public static SomeType TestMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

The default visibility is `internal` for types and `private` for members of a type definition. The `App_Code` folder gets compiled into its own assembly, different from the assembly that is created when compiling the code behinds. `internal` types cannot be shared between assemblies (that's not 100% true but true in this case), hence why you are having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make it public static.

```
public class TestClass{
   public static TestMethod(){}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure TestClass is public:

```
public class TestClass
{
}
```

The default when adding a class to Visual Studio is to omit the "public".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have at least 'internal' scope on your method prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Just because your class is static doesn't mean that it is accessible to all code/assemblies. Make sure that your static class has an access modifier (i.e. public) that is accessible by your web form.